# Installing gurobipy package in a custom virtual enviroment in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, gurobi, pythoninterpreter

First of all thanks in advance, and sorry if I made the question too long, I tried to be the clearest as possible.

I am trying to install the gurobipy module in my enviroment on Pycharm. I have already installed gurobi on my computer (Version 9.0.2) which is compatible with Python 3.7

But I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gurobipy'`when I am trying. I check on my interpreter installed packages, and the gurobipy package is not listed as installed (not a surprise until here)

In order to install it I go to my project interpreter, install packages, look for gurobipy and click install. But I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement gurobipy (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for gurobipy
```

[image]

I tried to run the command `pip install --user gurobipy` on my pycharm terminal as recomended in the error window but I get the following:

```
Requirement already satisfied: gurobipy in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (9.0.1)
```

If I type `pip list` on my terminal I can see that the gurobipy version is gurobipy 9.0.1.

I would really grateful if you could give me any idea of what is happening here. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

There is no `pip` package for gurobipy, yet. Please navigate to your Gurobi home directory and run `python setup.py install` while your environment is active.

You may also use the conda installation package as described [here](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.0/quickstart_windows/ins_the_anaconda_python_di.html#section:Anaconda).

This [guide](https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360044290292-Installing-Gurobi-for-Python) explains the different ways to install the Gurobi Python extension and should help you get started.